# Lumen 5.7.5 breaks Binding Resolution

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container, lumen

**UPDATE**:

**[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324008/lumen-5-7-5-breaks-binding-resolution/53373140#53373140)**

Lumen Version: 5.7.5

PHP Version: 7.2

I've just done an upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 to 5.7 until 5.7.4 everything works as expected, as soon as I pull in 5.7.5.
`PHP Artisan` gives me

"Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable."

Example:

PHP artisan

In Container.php line 945:

Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable.
Steps To Reproduce:
upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 to 5.7 and fin ally from 5.7.4 to 5.7.5.

I'm checking all the code changes and what could be causing this.

Maybe you guys have an idea ?

Here is the stack trace:

```
[2018-11-15 15:30:50] local.ERROR: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:945
Stack trace:
0 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable('Illuminate\\Cont...')
1 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\\Cont...')
2 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
3 project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(260): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
4 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(1222): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
5 project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(223): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#6 project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(117): Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException))
#7 project/artisan(43): Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target [Illuminate\\Contracts\\Debug\\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. at project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:945)
#[stacktrace]
#0 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->notInstantiable('Illuminate\\\\Cont...')
#1 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('Illuminate\\\\Cont...')
#2 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(609): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\\\Cont...', Array)
#3 project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(260): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('Illuminate\\\\Cont...', Array)
#4 project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(1222): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->make('Illuminate\\\\Cont...')
#5 project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(223): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->offsetGet('Illuminate\\\\Cont...')
#6 project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(117): Laravel\\Lumen\\Console\\Kernel->reportException(Object(Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException))
#7 project/artisan(43): Laravel\\Lumen\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main}
```

I've therefore created an issue on Github:

https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lumen V5.7.6 a fix was released.

It basically boiled down to a path overwrite during bootstrapping.

The application.php in Lumen has been using the command `static:class` instead of the class path.

This was changed to `self:class` to reflect the correct current path.

[This is the commit that broke it](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/commit/425907aa4ba7540bce44960470362eaf594e9248)

[This is the commit that fixes it](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/commit/d973359b1714536c36cf989278b7be8eff3e30ad)

In some cases you may want to overwrite the base application path therefore you could add an alias when overwriting the base application path for example in an app.php while bootstrapping the application.

e.g.

```
$app->alias(overwrite\path\Application::class, \Laravel\Lumen\Application::class);
```

Hope this helps someone altho the new commit should fix any manual overwriting to reflect the correct class path.